# Php, remove key from an array red-handed

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove an item from an array. I can write this:

```
$item = array(
    'id' => 1
    'name' => 'name'
);

$item2 = $item;
unset($item2['id']);
$names[] = $item2;
```

but the last 3 lines are somewhat "cumbersome", soo un elegant. Can it be solved without creating $`item2` ? Something like:

```
$item = array(
    'id' => 1
    'name' => 'name'
);

$names[] = array_ignore_index('id', $item);
```

Comment: you can do unset($item['id']);

Comment: and after unset, you can use array_values($array) to reindex.

Comment: @deceze: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/red-handed

Comment: Yeah, *"in the act of committing a crime or doing something wrong or shameful"*...?! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest out of the box solution is to create a diff of the array keys:

```
$names[] = array_diff_key($item, array_flip(['id']));
```

See http://php.net/array_diff_key.

Answer (score 3):

From your codes, I can see that you are trying to get the names[] from item array. One possible simple solution for this specific scenario:

For example IF you have :

```
$items = array(
    array(
        //this is your item 1
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'name1'
    ),
    array(
        //this is item 2
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'name2'
    )
);
```

and you want to retrieve the names in the names array.

You can just do:

```
$names = array_column($items, 'name');
```

It will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "name1"
    [1] => "name2"
)
```

Please note this solution is best fit for this specific scenario, it may not fit your current scenario depending.

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_ignore_index($id,$item){ ///function 
     unset($item[$id]);
     return $item;
   }
$a=array('id'=>1,
     'name'=>'name');
$b=array_ignore_index('name',$a);
echo $b['name']; //create error id is not present
```

Here is the code for required operation..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unset array column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

Code is

```
unset($item['id']);
```

To test it

```
print_r($item);
```